# jquery form validator help text styling

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I need some help with the jquery Form Validator by Victor Jonsson.  Everything works great, I just need help in trying to style the help text. I just want to change the text color so it stands out form the rest of the form. So for example, I have help message for everyone of my text boxes. (data-validation-help="Enter your First Name") so when the user gets focus on the First Name input box, this help message will show up in a different css color. I have tried many different ways to style this without any success.

When I take a look in Firebug, I get this information:

so I get this long class jquery_form_help_applicant_first_name help help-block and then I see a style="display: none;" generated. I cannot figure out where this is getting generated form. Secondly I have tried using many different css class without any success. So can someone please help me in getting the jquery form validator help text styled. Thanks a million in advanced!

BTW, I tried posting some screen shots to help people understand my questions but since I am new to Stackflow, I need at least 10 reputation to post images. Seems counter productive, when trying to get help.

Thanks,

D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the .help or .help-block class are being applied to the error text you are trying to change, then just add

```
.help-block {
    color: red;
}
```

To your stylesheet and that should let you change the color.

Comment: The class that is being added to the error by the validation plugin is .form-error http://jsfiddle.net/X5XQZ/

Comment: WOW. I thought I had used very combination but I must have not used this one .help-block.  I think I tried                                       help .help_block { color: green; }   but anyway just using         .help-block worked. Thanks!!!!